# Adding root user to mysql wheel

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a database on my external hard drive, so I mounted this hard drive, and I created a symlink in `/var/lib/mysql` to my database folder.

But because I mount my hard drive as `root` user and mysql user is `mysql` I cannot access to that database.

Is it possible to add `root` user to mysql wheel ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding root to the mysql group won't do anything at all, and adding mysql to the wheel group probably won't do anything terribly useful for you. There are ways and ways of fixing a problem like this...  Your general problem is that the mysql server cannot read and write your files owned by root.

While the mysql server can be setup to run as the root user (by removing the --user=mysql line from the startup script, perhaps) this is an exceptionally poor idea.  A much better line of inquiry is to make the files suitable to be read and written to by the mysql user.

I'm hoping that perhaps you have a simple file permission problem, and need only run the [Ubuntu Manpage: chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/chown.1.html) utility to make the database be owned by mysql like so:

```
chown -R mysql /path/to/your/external/database
```

and then restart the mysql daemon.

Ahh, the chown didn't work, even though you ran it as root? Oh Dear.

Maybe it said operation not permitted on this device? You may have got a fat32 filesystem on a usb stick or something?  Perhaps [mounting](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/mount.8.html) the device as the mysql user instead of root will fix it for you:

```
umount /path/to/external/device
mount -t vfat -o uid=mysql /dev/foo /path/to/external/device
```

That should make all files on the device report that they are owned by the mysql user, which should resolve the trouble.

Though if you're going to use this as a long-term solution it would be wise to reformat the device into a native linux filesystem at some point so it can have real users and permissions on it. ... and always backup your data first! ^_^

EDIT:
You may, if you like use use the --bind argument to mount to get the directory to show up in more than one location, but operations like remapping the user id will not work.  If you want to remap the userid, unmount the physical device, mount the physical device with -o uid=mysql and then once the entire disk is available with the userid of mysql, feel free to --bind it to multiple locations.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use your command the database will mount as `root` again ! I use this command because I want mount a folder: `sudo mount --bind -t vfat -o uid=mysql /media/hdd/server/databases /media/mysql`